How to customize swagger.json filename in .net 8 with swashbuckle
I tried to split a swagger document into different parts under the same version such that I can then acces them in endpoint, like this :
app.UseSwagger(s =>
{
    s.SerializeAsV2 = true;
})
.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger-file1.json", "File1 API V1");
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger-file2.json", "File2 API V1");
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger-file3.json", "File3 API V1");
})

Unfortunately I cannot find a way to customize the swagger-file1.json part.
I tried to research everywhere but could not find anything that helped this particular problem

You could try with using "MapGet" to route the swagger files. For instance we have the files in root directory:

Then you could map like:
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        //c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/swagger.json", "customSwagger");
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger-file1.json", "File1 API V1");
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger-file2.json", "File2 API V1");
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger-file3.json", "File3 API V1");
    });
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapGet("/swagger/v1/{fileName}", async context =>
{
    string file= context.Request.RouteValues["fileName"].ToString();
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(await File.ReadAllTextAsync(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), file)));
});

Test

